# integral of multiplication is multiplication of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

what conditions have to be met to be true:

$\iint_{XY}f(x)g(y)\,dx\,dy = \int_Xf(x)\,dx\int_Yg(y)\,dy$

we can assume that $\int_X|f(x)|\,dx < \infty$ and $\int_Y|g(y)|\,dy < \infty$

Comment: It is enough if both integrals on RHS exist.

Comment: @drhab RHS= real hilbert space? sorry I am not into math papers

Comment: RHS="right hand side" in this context. By equality $a=b$ we have RHS $b$ and LHS $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They need to be independent:

$$\int_Y(\int_Xf(x)g(y)dx)dy=\int_Y(g(y)\int_Xf(x)dx)dy=\int_Yg(y)dy\int_Xf(x)dx$$

$g(y)$ is treated as a constant, when integrating over $x$ and $\int_Xf(x)dx$ is a constant, when integrating over $y$. Since they are independent I can move them outside of integrals.